# Why Storyboard in Xcode showed correct, but when Run on my phone or simulator the view is wrong like the picture showed

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

Why Storyboard in Xcode showed correct, but when Run on my phone or simulator the view is wrong like the picture showed like bellowing:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: So it is about the top padding? You really need to be more specific here.

Comment: It seems you did set constraints for your "Scene View" but not for the other elements on this controller. Better start on some beginner tutorials on how to design with storyboard.